# Mongodb exact phrase search

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

As I understood from Mongodb documentation of text search.
if i want to search about `Java or (coffee shop)`
I need to do it like 
`{$text:{$search:"Java \"coffee shop\""}}`
[Exact Phrase search in mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/#exact-phrase)
so it should return all the documents contain `Java or (coffee shop)`.
but it acts exactly as `Java and (coffee shop)`.
so I think that i didn't get it right from the documentation.
so please.
I need clear explanation for why i got that result?
and 
how to get the required output `Java or (coffee shop)`?

Comment: According to that same documentation, "Use the $text query operator to perform text searches on a collection with a `text index`." Do you have such an index in the collection you're searching? If not, then that's likely your problem.

Comment: @B.Fleming thanks for your response.
I do have the index it is set exactly as in the documentation. At the link attached to the question.
Just checked it and it is there.
So this isn't the problem.

Comment: @AhmedShaltout this is a known issue, and is being tracker in [SERVER-30163](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30163). Please comment/upvote on the ticket to raise visibility on the issue.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha now i understand why it happens.
Thanks,
Sure i will do it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue,
and is being tracker in SERVER-30163.
Not Solved yet so please go to [SERVER-30163](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30163) to up-vote it.